# How to find the eVar Names in Adobe Workspace or Analytics

Tags: adobe-analytics

I am wondering that how to find the eVar names that are already implemented in the Adobe analytics.

Please let me know how to find in the bulk of all implemented eVars that will help me better understand user flows and build the charts efficiently.

Comment: If you did not keep record of this or inherited it from someone else or whatever, your next steps are to look at each report individually and see if there is data (which will tell you if _something_ was implemented, but not necessarily if it was done correctly), and audit the site code deployed.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to get bulk settings info. The most comprehensive is the Adobe Health Dashboard- https://express.adobe.com/page/tnNQGNlfzta3b/. Thisnot only tells you what each variable is named and what its settings are, but also shows you what type of data it is receiving. The downside is it requires adobe.io authorization, which can be a pain to get set up. It also only runs on PCs (because of its excel macros). I believe it also really only shows one report suite at a time.
You can also use tools like https://reportsuites.com/ to just get an export of variables and their settings.... it's particularly useful if you want ot compare across report suites. The main downside there is that adobe has made it hard to find the web services API credentials you need in order to run it.